# Custom Error page is not displaying on bad request (400 error)

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, error-handling, web-config, buffer

I have added a custom error page to handle long query strings. If the query string is too large it should have to redirect to a custom error page. It is working fine in my local and production server. But in test server, its showing the yellow page by saying
"To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off"."

In my configuration file I have set redirect URL. Still seems its loading some other configuration file.

I tried different ways to redirect to my custom page on bad requests. Still no luck.

```
<configuration> 
    <system.web> 
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="customerror.aspx"/> 
    </system.web> 
</configuration>
```

Comment: Please post relevant code to understand what you have done.

Comment: <configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="customerror.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>